# JSON Serialization with nested relationships among multiple objects

Tags: json

I have 4 objects(Account,custom1, custom2, custom3) with the following relationships:

1. Account and custom1 has master detail relation.
2. Custom1 and custom2 has lookup relation.
3. Custom2 and custom3 has lookup relation.

I would like to serialize some of the fields on these objects into JSON  based on the `AccountId` post to the REST API on salesforce from external service. I was able to serialize the fields on Account and Custom1 since they are directly related now based on the custom1 I have to get the custom2 fields and similarly based on custom2 have to get the custom3 fields for serialization into JSON. Using the JSON.Serialize I can just get the account and custom 1 fields. Can you please suggest me on how to handle multiple objects in the serialization.

Answer (score 1):

Your data model is analogous in levels to Opportunity - OpportunityLineItem - PricebookEntry - Product2

If you use SFDC Workbench REST Explorer with this query

```
select id,name,
  (select id, quantity, priceBookEntry.unitPrice, pricebookEntry.product2.productCode
    from OpportunityLineItems)
  from Opportunity where id='xxx'
```

You'll see how SFDC will JSON serialize the results:

```
{ "totalSize" : 1, "done" : true, "records" : 
   [ { "attributes" : { 
       "type" : "Opportunity", 
       "url" : "/services/data/v33.0/sobjects/Opportunity/006J000000IDHEhIAP" }, 
       "Id" : "006J000000IDHEhIAP", 
       "Name" : "MyOppoName", 
       "OpportunityLineItems" : { 
         "totalSize" : 1, 
         "done" : true, 
         "records" : [ 
           { "attributes" : { 
              "type" : "OpportunityLineItem", 
              "url" : "/services/data/v33.0/sobjects/OpportunityLineItem/00kJ0000008Tw5nIAC" },
              "Quantity" : 1.0, 
              "PricebookEntry" : { 
                 "attributes" : { 
                    "type" : "PricebookEntry", 
                    "url" : "/services/data/v33.0/sobjects/PricebookEntry/01uJ000000BUzNtIAL" }, 
                    "UnitPrice" : 0.0, 
                    "Product2" : { 
                        "attributes" : { 
                        "type" : "Product2", 
                        "url" : "/services/data/v33.0/sobjects/Product2/01tJ0000004HBbWIAW" }, 
                        "ProductCode" : "MyProductCode" 
     } } } ] 
   } } 
  ] 
 }
```

If your target system for this JSON happens to also be SFDC, the structure is super convenient as it can be deserialized by the target system directly into sobjects.

However, if your target system has its own JSON structure, you are best of modelling that with inner classes as @susanoochidori suggests. You'll need to do the aforementioned SOQL in your APEX (changing to your custom objects from the OOB example I used) and then, map with assignment statements and inner class instanatiation the values returned from SOQL. Finally, serialize `OuterWrapper`.

Put another way, you may need to work backwards from the JSON signature expected by the target system into a corresponding APEX outer with inner classes object model